# Make SWIG split generated code into header and cpp file

Tags: swig

I'm generating some C++ code with SWIG, and currently it dumps everything into a single `.cpp` file.  Is there any way to make it put `#define`s, function declarations, type declarations, etc into a `.h` file so that I can `#include` and use it from somewhere else in my program.

I've written a lot of code in SWIG extension blocks like the `%header % {}` blocks, etc, and this code would be much better represented in a standalone `.cpp` file that I link into my project along side the SWIG generated code.  But this code makes use of some of the other generated functions and definitions, so it won't have visibility of any of these symbols from another file, so I need a header file.

Is anything like this possible?